# How to detect Video does not exist state from url in AVPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am playing videos from urls in AVPlayer. It is working fine. But, Few videos keep loading but not player, I checked them in browser and they are showing **Video does not exist**.

So, How to detect that video does not exist state and how to show alert for end user understands.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupAVAudioSession()
        
    }

  func playVideo(){
        
        if let str = videoUrl{
            
            if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: str) {
                
                player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
                player?.rate = 1 //auto play
                let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 210)
                let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                playerViewController.delegate = self
                playerViewController.player = player
                playerViewController.view.frame = playerFrame
                playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
                addChild(playerViewController)
                videoPlayerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
            }
        }
    }

 func setupAVAudioSession(){
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
        }
    }

func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willBeginFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
}

func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    playerViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I don't know exactly, but after search I found this, maybe this is what you want: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1643486-reasonforwaitingtoplay

Comment: I have fixed this by backend team. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check existence of your video url by sending `HEAD` request before start playing it e.g.:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil,
        let r = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        r.statusCode == 200
    else {
        print("url is not valid")
        return
    }
    
    print("url is valid")
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: this is working like charm. But, we fixed our issue by backend side. Thank you, Upvoted and accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have not get any fix for this from mobile side, So, we have fixed this from backend side.